# How to create shortcut for command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I have a big command to run the program. This command is usually static.
How to create a script or something that I could run just using `./start` (or even run from desktop(I use arch linux)) that will execute my command like that `/home/user/program --argument1 --argument2 --argument3 --argument4 --argument5 ...`?
And is it possible to make this script dynamic so that I can add/replace arguments?
Hope for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a short bash script to do this but I think what your looking for is shell aliases you can add aliases to your bashrc or separate alias file.  See example below.

```
alias name=‘command —argument —argument —argument’
```

Now every time you run `name` it will run the full command.

Remember aliases will not work from within shell scripts unless it is run in interactive mode. See example below.

```
#!/bin/bash -i
```

If you want to make a short bash script because the arguments are long or you want to keep a list of the common commands you use you could do something like.

```
#!/bin/bash

command —argument \
—argument \
—argument 
# —argument \
—argument
```

You can name the script something short so it is easy to run just remember it has to be in a location that is in your PATH.

Any of the arguments with `#` will be ignored so you can change up what is run.  As you learn more about bash scripts you can add if and else statements, loops the sky is the limit that is why the shell/terminal are so powerful.

There are lots of ways to do what you asked about in Linux and if you ask 10 people you will probably hear several different ways of doing it.  With bash as with most things in Linux you can accomplish the same outcome from a hundred different ways some are better then others, some may be a few key strokes shorter then another but the way I look at is keep it readable because no matter how smart you are when you come back to your code or script months from now you will forget what you where thinking at the time.  So keep it readable yes you might be able to save two or three key presses doing it a different way and some of that will come with time and experience but at first keep it so you understand it not someone else that told you.  If you don’t understand why it does what it does then you learned  nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can name an alias in your `~/.bash_profile`

It's usually on your home directory (otherwise you can just create the file). For example, to make an alias of `ls -a` to just type `la` you just need to add a line in your `~/.bash_profile` as:

```
alias la='ls -a'
```

Save the changes and `source ~/.bash_profile` :-)